# How to hide page name and extension of website

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </configSections>
    <rewriter>
        <rewrite url="~/User_login/(.+)-(.+).aspx" to="~/User_login"/>
    </rewriter>
    <system.web>            
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Page Path:**
    D:\Applications\WebSite1\User_login.aspx

When i run my website getting **`http://192.518.9.10/WebSite1/User_login.aspx`**
I have to hide page name and extension of website
 (Have to display like this `http://192.518.9.10/WebSite1`)

For that purpose google suggest me URL Rewriting.
So write rules in web.config file but stiill getting page name with extension

Comment: the rewrite url `~/User_login/(.+)-(.+).aspx` does not match the example path `/WebSite1/User_login.aspx`.